# Invalid Redirect URI in Google Drive

Tags: google-oauth

In creating a client id in the developer console, I need to specify a redirect URI, but I only have an IP address.  Such has worked on other oAuth systems, like Box, DropBox, Evernote, and OneNote.  But not Google Drive?

One other place where others had problems...
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-plus-developers/6j6JNmewCXI

One user said to use FQDN, not IP address.  Others complained that IP address was required, no resolution for them.  So, I'm also stuck.

Any way I can use IP, not FQDN?  Google does not document this one way or another.  And use of IP addresses is supported in the oAuth specification.

Comment: Thanks Owen.  Yes, the console does say that; I was hoping to know whether the requirement was temporary, or that there was a configurable workaround, or what other users did.  For me, I used a dynamic DNS service - a temporary workaround.  But we don't know for how long.  Using FQDN requires either we buy a new domain or that we piggyback onto our own domain.  If we do the former, that's an expense and management issue against company policy.  If  we do the latter, we are subject to bureaucracy in our own IT group.  We will use a proper public FQDN when our POC is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the google console setting says: Authorized redirect URI needs to have a protocol, no URL fragments, and no relative paths. Can't be a public IP Address.

You can use IP address, but protocol (either http or https) is required.